# Trace IP Address

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to trace the ip address (where my website access) for optional loading of my theme.

Explanation:

I want to add a share link to twitter and facebook in my application. i think in some countries like china; twitter is blocked. Thats why i need to check from where my site is accessing otherwise this may affect my site's performance.

How can we solve this problem in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GeoIP is the better way to get location infromation by ip address.
You can get by this solution information as City, State, Country, Longitude, Latitude and much more like ISP name.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP you can access the IP address of the visitor in the variable:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Check out the following [Link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)